# How to look at a certain value/category of a variable according to another one (Large dataset)

Tags: r, dplyr, count, subset, summary

I'm writing this question according to another problem I have in R studio. I have a very large dataset that consists of movement data (ACC) for birds and I have multiple rows per individuals (each row represents a timestamp).
In my dataset, I need to look at how many individuals I have in a certain territory.
The problem here is that I have many rows for each individual, and using simple function like table or summary returns the number of rows assigned to this territory. What I would like is to know individuals that belong to the territory, using a simple function.

This is what I've done so far:

- I have many rows in my dataframe, but only around 50 individuals (that have multiple rows each).
- I have around 15 territories in total, and each row has one territory ID (repeated).

I've tried to use table

```
table(df$territory_id) %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% head
```

which gives me the output:

```
ter1  ter2  ter3  ter4  ter5  ter6 
275034 207746 232739 165260 162103 259644
```

Here I have the number of rows that have the territory ID. Because I wanted to know how many different individuals belong in a territory, I've subsetted the territories in separate object and done tables for that:

```
t <- filter(df, territory == "ter1")
```

and then:

```
table(t$individualID)
```

which gave me the output I wanted. However, I need to repeat the process for each territory.

I would like to know if there is a simpler way to do that? I only have 15 territories but if I had more, that would take a lot of time to repeat the function. Is there a simpler way to do that?

Comment: hi Skyk! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you edit your question, and include a sample dataframe? dput(df) or dput(head(df)) could be handy

Comment: thank you ! I would like to ! I just don't know how to do it (should I put it as code?), and the problem is that the data is for a master thesis and my tutor asked me not to share it unfortunately. I'm also very new to R studio and I don't know how to create dataframes on my own, I will try it though.

Comment: that's alright! If you can create similar code, that would work too. Create the code, then edit your question to add it in

Comment: it sounds like you're very early in your R journey though, maybe an introductory course would be better

Comment: To give you something slightly more specific to search for, check out tutorials using the `dplyr` package and `summarise` - you can specify a grouping variable (e.g. `territory_id`).

Comment: Hey ! Actually, I've already done an introductory course, same for dplyr and summarise package. The problem is that I can't seem to find any tutorial on doing what I look for. So I will look now

Comment: That's it, I decided to put the first few lines of my code to show you how my data is. Like you told me, I've searched everywhere but even by using simple functions it doesn't work. Each time I summarise, it gives me the number of rows where the territory appears. I just want to know which individuals are in the territory once.

Comment: thank you for doing that. I think if you're worried about sharing your data, you don't need to share all of those columns- I edited your question to remove the non-relevant ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems like it's quite large, so while your head gives an idea of what the data looks like, it's not great to work with (because it seems like it's six timestamps for one bird in one location). So I created my own, which is hopefully still similar:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(
    bird_id = rep(1:10, each = 10),
    territory_id = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 100, replace = TRUE),
    timestamp =  ymd_hms("2023-01-01 12:00:00") + sample(1:10000000, 100, replace = TRUE))
```

```
> head(df)
  bird_id territory_id           timestamp
1       1            I 2023-03-05 03:57:14
2       1            D 2023-01-01 21:06:37
3       1            G 2023-03-01 07:23:02
4       1            A 2023-02-23 01:09:48
5       1            B 2023-03-29 22:41:45
6       1            G 2023-01-29 03:29:01
```

So while it's clear to me you want to analyse your dataset, I'm unsure what specifically you are trying to do. So here are a few things you *could* be wanting, and how you could do them:

```
# 1. get the number of birds you have seen at any point in each territory
df |>
  distinct(territory_id, bird_id) |>
  count(territory_id)

# 2. count the number of rows in your dataset for each territory
count(df, territory_id)

# 3. count the number of rows in your dataset for each territory and bird

count(df, territory_id, bird_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes ! That's what I wanted to know ! Thank you so much !
Basically I've looked at the first code you provided:

```
df |>
distinct(territory_id, bird_id) |>
count(territory_id)
```

and it returned something like:

```
  territory_id     n
  <chr>        <int>
  1 GR002            2
  2 GR009            1
  3 GR011            1
```

etc...

But here I wanted to know the individualID that belong to the territory (maybe then I put instead):

```
df |>
distinct(territory_id, bird_id) |>
count(territory_id, bird_id)
```

and it returned me:

```
  <chr>        <chr>                    <int>
  1 GR002        individual1 (eobs 5860)          1
  2 GR002        individual2 (eobs 5861)          1
  3 GR009        individual3 (eobs 6483)          1
```

which gives me what I want. So I just need to use the count function...Thank you !

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help  don't forget to mark your question answered